# Is it good to paint old concrete roof tiles in a light color?

Tags: tile, roof, painting

Our house is around 50 years old and has dark concrete roof tiles that have never been painted. I am wondering whether it is a good idea to paint them in white or a light color to deflect sunlight and hopefully keep the house cooler in summer. I have heard many different, sometimes conflicting, opinions about this.

Comment: who is conflicting it and why

Comment: @Ruskes Simply put, some say never do it, some say you must do it.

Comment: OK, do me a favor, take two sheets of paper one black and one white. Now go in the sun and look at them

Comment: Some say painting concrete roof tiles (regardless of the color) is wasteful and creates further maintenance issues with little benefit.

Comment: do the paper test than talk to me about the results, or do you have to wait for 6 months for sun to show up

Comment: depends on your climate

Comment: Too little information to say if painting will give you enough benefits.  A white/light roof should reduce attic temperatures quite a bit from the sunlight heating it.  Will need location, cost of paint, insulation/ventilation of the house plus a few other factors to know if you can have savings from painting.

Answer (score 2):

I had dark concrete tiles on my Florida roof. The paint eventually washed off after being power washed many times. I painted the tiles in a much lighter color and noticed my AC running less and the attic cooler. An additional advantage was lowering the heat on the roofing material below the tiles to slow down drying and cracking.

Comment: Did it feel colder in winter after painting the tiles in a lighter color?

Comment: @Reza  I never really noticed that. We don't have much winter down here in south Florida and any cool weather is welcomed with open arms.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Arizona, where it gets 120 F in summer.

I have flat roof, and it is painted in WHITE.

Granted it is not concrete tiles roof, but white color does reflect sun regardless what is painted over.